# Using tensorflow, how to operate on top_k and then create a new tensor with original tensor and modified top_k

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I've been trying to do something pretty simple, but with no success. I have a tensor (say `X` of shape `(None, 128)` containing some scores, in other words each batch has 128 scores. Now I apply `Y = tf.math.top_k(X, k=a).indices` here `a` indicates the top `a` scores. Let us consider for simplicity, `a = 95`. Then the shape of tensor `Y` will be `(None, 95)`. Till here it is fine.

Now my original `data` tensor is of shape `(None, 3969, 128)`. I wanted to do some operation on the datas having top_k scores. So I extracted the datas using:

```
ti = tf.reshape(Y, [Y.shape[-1], -1])   # Here ti is of shape (95, None)
fs = tf.gather(X, ti[:, 0], axis=-1)    # Here fs is of shape (None, 3969, 95)
```

and then did my operation by say `Z = fs * 0.7    # Here Z is of shape (None, 3969, 95)`. This was also fine.

Now I want to create a new tensor `F` such that, firstly `F` is of shape `(None, 3969, 128)`, containing all the unchanged datas (datas whose scores do not fall in top_k) and modified datas (datas whose scores falls under top_k and have been modified in `Z`) but, the order of these datas will be same as in original datas i.e., modified datas should still be in their original position. **Here is where I am stuck**.

I am relatively new with TensorFlow, so apologies if I'm missing anything simple or being unclear. Have been stuck with it for a few days now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do so is to use [`tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update?hl=en#folded_indices). You'll have to convert the indices from the topk function to something that works with your data though. For that, you can use a combination of tf.tile and tf.unravel_index to convert from the `X` shape to your `data` shape.

If we assume 3D data like you have, you could use something similar to this:

```
# getting the dimensions of the data tensor
# assuming that the shape of X is (B,N) and the shape of data is (B,D,N)
B, D, N = tf.unstack(tf.shape(data))
topk = tf.math.top_k(X, k=k)
# to get the absolute indices in the original tensor, we need to:
# - tile to get indices from (B,N) to (B,D,N)
# - do index arithmetics to get indices on the flattened tensor
topk_idx_tiled = tf.tile(topk.indices[:,None,:], [1,D,1])
flattened_indices = tf.reshape(tf.reshape(tf.range(B*D)*N,(B,D))[...,None] + topk_idx_tiled, -1)
# unraveling to get indices with batch dimensions so that we have compatibility with scatter_nd
sc_idx = tf.transpose(tf.unravel_index(flattened_indices, tf.shape(data)))
# scattering the updates to update the original data 
updates = tf.reshape(tf.tile(topk.values[:,None,:],[1,D,1]),-1)*0.7
F = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(data, sc_idx, updates)
```

Comment: thank you so much. Have been stuck with it for almost two days. Thank you very much. Really appreciated.